# I am trying to fix this pylint warning message

Tags: python, pylint

I am trying to install pylint and keep getting this error.

**Here the error message :**

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out.
>   (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/   ERROR: Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement pylint (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are using a vpn or behind some firewall and hence pypi.org is not accessible.

Comment: The title is very misleading; this question is about `pip` not being able to connect to the server

Comment: Thank you! I am using a VPN, I appreciate the help!